# Swift - button made programmatically isn't perfect circle? Flat edges?

Tags: swift

Im working in Swift and I have created a button programmatically. I use ratios when I make things programmatically because I have had many issues with auto layout. Im running it on a 5s so the ratio is correct. My code:

```
menuBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width * (50/330), screenSize.height * (50/568))
        menuBtn1.backgroundColor = colorWithHexString(chosenColor)
        menuBtn1.layer.cornerRadius = menuBtn1.bounds.width*0.5
        menuBtn1.clipsToBounds = true
        menuBtn1.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5, screenSize.height * (0.88))
        menuBtn1.addTarget(self, action: ":", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(menuBtn1)
```

while the ratio may be the problem I even had this issue when just setting height and width to 50 and 50. My circle us not perfect - it has flat edges:
[image]

This isn't a huge problem however it doesn't look great - how can I make a perfect circle? Why are there edges?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A circle needs its `width` to be equal to is `height`:

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width * (50/330), screenSize.height * (50/568))
```

will definitely fail that precondition.

You probably want just:

```
let size = screenSize.width * (50 / 330)
menuBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that but still having problem (see picture in question)

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `width` and `height` are not equal.

The approach of using corner radius with half the width works only if the original button's shape is "square" in nature. Since your width and height aren't equal, you have a rectangular shape.

This would become more apparent, if you had a shape with much longer width than its height. Then the corner radius would not at all look circular, rather it would look like a rounded-rect.

This is more of a mathematical concept!

Feel free to ask any questions :)